# Create a Numpy scalar from dtype

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to create a numpy scalar of a specified dtype.  I know I could do, say, `x = numpy.int16(3)`, but I don't know the dtype in advance.

If I were to want an array then

```
dtype = int
x = numpy.array(3, dtype=dtype)
```

would do it, so I had high hopes for

```
x = numpy.generic(3, dtype=dtype)
```

but one cannot create an instance of `numpy.generic`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is.  Why doesn't `x = dtype(3)` do what you want?

Comment: @DSM: Strictly speaking, that doesn't do it. In the OP's example that would create `int(3)` instead of `numpy.int32(3)`. Whether that's an issue or not, I don't know.

Comment: @NPE: I'm assuming that by "of a specified dtype", the OP has put the wanted dtype in `dtype`; `int` will give `int`, `np.int16` will give `np.int16`.  I must be missing something, though, because the OP knows that you can call the type object (in the first line) and also that you can bind the type objects to `dtype`.

Comment: @DSM, sorry for confusion, I have code like `a = np.eye(2, dtype=int)`, `b = np.zeros(2, dtype=a.dtype)`, so `a.dtype` can be passed as a dtype argument, but `a.dtype(3)` gives a not-callable error.  The `.type` method does what I need ("make dtypes callable").

Answer (score 9):

The following will create a scalar of `x`'s dtype:

```
In [18]: val = x.dtype.type(3)

In [19]: val
Out[19]: 3

In [20]: type(val)
Out[20]: numpy.int32
```

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know about the `.type` method for dtypes

Comment: This however does not work for all dtypes nor does it preserve endian-ness for any dtype (always turns it into native endian). I believe the only way to preserve endian-ness and work with more dtypes (but probably still not all) is to create an array and get the element(s) from it.

Answer (score 9):

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805087/create-a-numpy-scalar-from-dtype#comment43344275_20805168), the accepted answer is not generally correct for all dtypes, for example timedeltas:

```
In [6]: d = np.dtype("timedelta64[10m]")

In [7]: d.type(3)
Out[7]: numpy.timedelta64(3)
```

To always get the correct answer use the following:

```
In [8]: np.array(3, d)[()]
Out[8]: numpy.timedelta64(3,'10m')
```

Answer (score 3):

In case someone would like to get the dtype from a string, you can use

```
import numpy as np
val = np.dtype('int32').type(3.0)
```